# Interactive push notification action button click not working

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am working on interactive push notifications first time. I am stuck on an issue with action button click. I have created push notification using code.

```
          let acceptAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
            acceptAction.identifier = "ACCEPT_REQUEST"
            acceptAction.title = "Accept"
            acceptAction.activationMode = .background
            acceptAction.isAuthenticationRequired = true
            acceptAction.isDestructive = false

            // Reject Action
            let rejectAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
            rejectAction.identifier = "REJECT_REQUEST"
            rejectAction.title = "Reject"
            rejectAction.activationMode = .background
            rejectAction.isAuthenticationRequired = true
            rejectAction.isDestructive = false

            let requestCategory = UIMutableUserNotificationCategory()
            requestCategory.identifier = "CONNECTION_REQUEST"

            let categoriesForSettings = NSSet(array: [requestCategory,clubRequestCategory,groupRequestCategory,referralCategory])//NSSet(objects: requestCategory)

            // Register the notification settings.
            let types:UIUserNotificationType = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            let newNotificationSettings = 
 UIUserNotificationSettings(types: types, categories: categoriesForSettings as! Set<UIUserNotificationCategory>)

UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(newNotificationSettings)
```

Here is the code I have written for handling push actions.

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, handleActionWithIdentifier identifier: String?, forRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

if(identifier == "ACCEPT_REQUEST" || identifier == "REJECT_REQUEST")
    {
        // API Call goes here 
    }

}
```

I have tried to debug code and I see log written in API function is printed but it doesn't reach the server. If I start an app from background API call successful and also get a response from the server. I am using Alamofire for API related stuff.

Can anyone help me to come out from this?

If anyone needs more details please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You're using deprecated methods.  Look at `UNNotificationAction` action instead.

```
private let categoryIdentifier = "AcceptOrReject"

private enum ActionIdentifier: String {
  case Accept, Reject
}

private func registerCustomActions() {
  let accept = UNNotificationAction(identifier: ActionIdentifier.Accept.rawValue,
                                    title: "Accept")
  let reject = UNNotificationAction(identifier: ActionIdentifier.Reject.rawValue,
                                    title: "Reject")

  let category = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: categoryIdentifier, actions: [accept, reject],
                                        intentIdentifiers: [])
  UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories([category])
}
```

Comment: I have tried this but not working for me. Still API call not reach to server.

Comment: Same issue is coming in my app, API response is not working on the action button clicked. you have find out any solution for this ?